# How to send multi-dimensional array in formData

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, multipartform-data, form-data

I have to send multiple images to the server which maps to multiple keys (variants). Lets say that I have two variants so one array would be of variant i.e, `variant = [a ,b]` and other array should contain images (multiple images) corresponding to each variant e.g `images = [[File, File], [File, File, File]]`, so the two nested arrays are linked to variant array as per index i.e, `variant[0]` has images `images[0]`. Similarly, images of `variant[1]` are in `images[1]` (three images).

Now, I have to send these data to backend from front end which is in React.js, with variant it's simple, something like this.

```js
const formData = new FormData()
const variants = [a, b, c]
for (let key of variants) {
  formData.append('variant[]', key)
}
```

Now, how do I make a `formData` body of the multi-dimensional array of images? I have done something like this which doesn't feel right.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < images[i].length; j++) {
    if (typeof images[i][j] !== 'object') continue
    formBody.append(`image_url[]${i}[]`, images[i][j])
  }
}
```

What is the right way of sending multidimensional in `formData`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in which format are your images, but assuming that they are all convertible to JSON. I would suggest you to do the following as it would keep the nesting of the arrays intact, and not spread them (which it does, if you pass the argument i.e. array directly).

```js
formData.append("images", JSON.stringify(imagesArray))
```

Comment: I have to send Files (blobs) the user will upload so no can't convert them to strings. Need them in File format only.

Comment: You can try "react-file-base64" library, as you are working in react. It will convert your files into base64 string, which then can be stringified. It's really easy to use. In case, you have something going on the server side which can only accept "blobs", then you might have to look for some other way around.

Answer (score 0):

So, instead of sending a multi-dimensional array, i had the body of end point changed, for every variant there's a key with that variant id. e.g;

```
variant=[a,b]
```

instead of sending

```
images = [[File, File], [File, File, File]]
```

I am now making a dynamic key and appending it to images key like this:

```
images_a[] = File
images_a[] = File
images_b[] = File
images_b[] = File
images_b[] = File
```

turns it it was much simpler approach.